You are using Node.js 16.20.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required
i just  install LTS verssion of node js 20.16.0 but in my system  it not applicable properly like if i run command  " node -v "  it shows latest version but when i try to run my project its throw Error you aree using  node js version 16 ........ many time i uninstall and install  .....anyone have solution how an i do .......
so many time i try to uninstall nodejs and try to reinstall LTS version ofnode js but still not working  .enter image description here

Did you try to restart your computer after install?

Install nvm(Node version manager) on your system. Once you install it, try changing Node version with it. This might help.
Another problem might be: Your project might be configured with Node@16 when you created it. Try removing node_modules directory and clean cache using npm cache clean --force or yarn cache clean. Re-install packages using npm install or yarn.

Clearly you didn't look at the image in the question

@JaromandaX,I edited the answer after checking the image, Did you check?

huh? Your answer doesn't look edited - you're still suggesting OP install nvm when clearly OP is using nvm

@JaromandaX, I did edit, but by mistake the text didn't get removed. Anyway, why do you mind?

I don't mind - I just pointing out that the first part of your answer is 100% redundant - and you didn't edit, since there is no edit history on your answer. Just sayin
